# How is the following for loop working?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am doing this in R. Though there is a shortcut way to do the following in R, I want to check it out:

```
   x <- c(7,6,8,7)
   y <- 1
   n <- length(x)
   p=1
   s = 0
   for(i in 1:n){
          s = s + (x^p * y^p)
   }

   s
```

Since I have not specified the index number of `x` in the for loop, I guessed that only the first element of `x` will be used. So I made a table:

```
    i     s= s + (x^p * y^p)
    1     s= 0 + (7^1 * 1^1)=7
    2     s= 7 + (7^1 * 1^1)=14
    3     s= 14 + (7^1 * 1^1)=21
    4     s= 21 + (7^1 * 1^1)=28
```

But the result was:

```
    s
   [1] 28 24 32 28
```

I couldn't match this result in any way. How does it work?

Comment: why are you using  `s = s + (x^p * y^p)` and not  `s <- s + (x^p * y^p)`

Comment: @LiranElisha it's a personal preference. The code is still valid (and identical).

Comment: Why do you guess when programming? Read the documentation. If you guess, you should at least check in a systematic way if your guess is valid.

Comment: @Roland when people ask me what I do, I usually answer "I mostly check if I made any mistakes". :)

Comment: Run your code line by line when you don't understand what it is doing. You can easily see that `c(7,6,8,7)` is being added to `s` in each loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is not a single integer, but a vector of integers. You need to subset your `x` the way god intended. When you specify `x`, R doesn't use just the first element, but all of them. This is the assumption that is clouding your solution.

```
x <- c(7,6,8,7)
y <- 1
n <- length(x)
p <- 1
s <- 0
for(i in 1:n){
  s <- s + (x[1]^p * y^p)
  message(s)
}

7
14
21
28
```

Comment: Actually i am accustomed with `C` program. i am beginner in `R`. Could you please tell me is the `massage` function working like `print`?

Comment: @harry yes, `message` holds a similar function as `print`. Type `?message` to see the details.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are really a nice person.